# UI falsely attributes migration to users who merely voted for closure

Tags: bug, migration, vote-to-close, closed-questions

I voted to close [a question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/142127/i-need-some-help-on-an-rpg-battle) today. Nothing new, except the closure turned into an unwanted migration. The question should NOT have been migrated, but all of a sudden my name was on it:

[image: Closed, migrated and rejected]

I voted to close as off-topic because it was broken. However, the question was unfit for Stack Overflow so I didn't vote for migration. However, it shows up like it did and I got called out on it. At the time, I had no idea why one might think I had migrated it, except the guys at SO didn't know any better:

> @Mast I didn't know that you didn't vote for migration; I just saw migrated to stackoverflow.com by forsvarir, Mathias Ettinger, Mast, Graipher, Jamal♦ 26 mins ago. – Antti Haapala

That's not helpful. The users who closed the question are already mentioned in the revision history. There's no reason why they should be mentioned as migration instigators if they didn't.

Comment: The full banner does list "broken code" with: forsvarir, Mathias Ettinger, Mast, Graipher as the voters. However-  as is the case with close votes network wide there's an order the "reason" is chosen in the history. Whatever a mod closes as - it's that, if a gold badge holder dupe closes it, then it's closed as a duplicate, otherwise it's the majority reason...

Comment: @JonClements That appears to be how it works, yes. And for closing the questions, that makes sense. What doesn't make sense is the same holds for migrations.

Comment: Well - normally - migrations normally only occur along the established paths which are to a couple of sites (plus the site's meta) and they require everyone voting to agree - so normally it wouldn't matter. It's just in a rare case a mod gets involved it looks "odd"... I have a feeling it's been brought up on MSE...

Comment: This is likely an SE-wide problem that should be reported on Meta.se.

Comment: +1 for also being on the list of people who seem to have voted to migrate it but actually voted to close it...